# How do I populate a TextView from a Cursor without using ListAdapter

Tags: android

In my app I use the following code to populate my ListView:

```
// Populate the ListView w/ all rows
Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataAllBonuses();
listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bonus_list_row_item, data,
                new String[] {"sCode", "sName", "sCategory", "sCity", "sState"},
                new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName, R.id.bonusListCategory, R.id.bonusListCity, R.id.bonusListState}, 0));
```

Once I have tapped on a row, I go to a new Intent, and in this new intent I have a series of TextView's that need to show the same info as above.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547917/problem-with-populating-textviews-from-db-rowid), which seems to be the right track, but I'm still not sure how to populate the layout with the data from the DB.

How do I populate a TextView with data from the Cursor since ListAdapter doesn't seem to be applicable?

(Note, I am not using an `OnClickListener` in my code as I'm not actually tapping on the ListView row itself. Instead I have a FrameLayout to allow differing intents to trigger based on if the left or right side of the row is tapped on).

EDIT: Here is my AppDBAdapter:

```
public class AppDataDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String TAG = "AppDataDBHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
    private static String DB_NAME ="appdata.db";
    private static String DB_TABLE = "Bonus_Data";
    private static int DB_VERSION = 1;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;

    public AppDataDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null,DB_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        Log.e(TAG,"Entered createDatabase");
        boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
        if(!mDataBaseExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try {
                //Copy the database from assets
                copyDataBase();
                Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
            } catch (IOException mIOException) {
                throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
            }
        }
    }

    //See if DB exists in userspace
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        Log.e(TAG,"entered checkDatabase");
        File dbFile = new File(mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath());
        if (dbFile.exists()) return true;
        Log.e(TAG,"dbFile = true");
        File dbDir = dbFile.getParentFile();
        if (!dbDir.exists()) {
            Log.e(TAG,"dbFile = false");
            dbDir.mkdirs();
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Copy the database from assets to userspace
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream mInput;
        OutputStream mOutput;
        String outFileName = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

        try {
            mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = mInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                mOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            mOutput.flush();
            mOutput.close();
            mInput.close();
        } catch (IOException ie) {
            throw new Error("copyDatabase() Error");
        }
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataFilteredBonuses() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE sState = 'CA'", null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataTrophyRuns() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE sTrophyGroup IS NOT NULL GROUP BY sTrophyGroup", null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataAllBonuses() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " ORDER BY sCode", null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataSelectedBonus(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String [] args={id};
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE sCode = ? ORDER BY sCode", args);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getAppDataListContents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT hMy as _id,* FROM " + DB_TABLE, null);
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can manually get all the data from the cursor that you want and put that into holders (lists, arrays, whatever) either pass or grab those (or do this with the cursor data and do in there). Get all the textviews and set all the data to them. There's multiple ways to go about it.

Comment: I assumed there were multiple ways to accomplish this, but if I knew how to do what your comment suggests, I wouldn't have needed to post the question in the first place. Are you able to suggest a specific method of taking the Cursor and putting it into a TextView without using ListAdapter or OnClickListener? I'm happy to post more code if that would be useful, just tell me what you need.

Comment: I use comments as I will not spend the time to spell everything out. You can find all this already by searching. For example if you look at this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor you'll see stuff like moveToNext() which is part of how data is retrieved from cursor. You can find tutorials, etc on this by searching. You can put that data into ArrayList, Hasmap, etc whatever and then create string and setText on TextView and bam! Cursor data populated the TextView(s).

Comment: Please post the entire Adapter code so that we can have a look, thanks.

Comment: @Enzokie I have modified my question.

Comment: Given the ff views `(bonusListCode, bonusListName, bonusListCategory, bonusListCity, bonusListState)` which views are tappable and which are not?

Comment: @Enzokie Sorry for the delay, I was out of town. None of those are tappable. I have a frame layout in my cell view that has a left (`leftSideRowTapper`) and right (`rightSideRowTapper') as a top layer. That is what is tappable.

Comment: @DJFriar no worries, not the most detailed answer but you need to use `ViewBinder` for this.